# Discord bot is not going online

Tags: python, discord.py

I use repl.it to make my Discord bot. I used Python and followed this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPTfmiYiuok

and here is my code:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client ()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
   await message.channel.send('Hello!')
   
my_secret = os.environ['token']
```

Comment: Read the documentation https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ discord py got rewrited years ago

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing `client.run(my_secret)`